# IntelliJ idea Scala project on Mac

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I installed latest version of IntelliJ on my macbook. I also installed scala plugin.

when I create a project it asks me to specify "Project SDK"

my java is installed in /usr/bin/java

but when I click on the button next to the project sdk i can only see my home directory. I cannot specify the java sdk path.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the steps listed at https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html#d1278485e208 ?

Comment: Ah ... thanks. actually java was already there

Comment: /Library/Java/Java Virtual Machines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk